# Loop through JSON data and store it in array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, xcode

So I have JSON data that's in an array (0 is first day of month up until last day of month).

How do I do a loop to go through the whole array and store the 3 times of the day each in their own array (I wish to use these times for notifications later)

The dayForArray variable is just the current day - 1 so that it matches the number in the JSON array.

```
func parseJSON(_ timesData: Data) -> TimesModel? {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(TimesData.self, from: timesData)
        let time1 = decodedData.data[dayForArray].timings.Time1
        let time2 = decodedData.data[dayForArray].timings.Time2
        let time3 = decodedData.data[dayForArray].timings.Time3

        let time = TimeModel(time1: time1, time2: time2, time3: time3)

        return times

    } catch {
        delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error)
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you're saying that this code works, but just for one day, `dayForArray`, and you want it to apply to each day in the month?

Comment: Yes it's working now. But it's only storing the current day's times and that's it. I'd like to grab the whole JSON array and store them so that I can notify users of these 3 time's throughout the day without having to check the app every day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to use `map` to create an array of `TimeModel` objects from your json array

```
let times = decodedData.data.map { 
    TimeModel(time1: $0.timings.Time1, 
              time2: $0.timings.Time2, 
              time3: $0.timings.Time3) 
}
```

Comment: Ok so I'm getting somewhere.. I added that but now got the error "Cannot convert return expression of type '[TimeModel]' to return type 'TimeModel?'" I thought this is because in my TimeModel I list the 3 times as Strings, I changed those to array (not sure if I should have?) and now I'm getting "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments". Thanks for the help

Comment: @MichaelScott your function is declared to return a TimeModel, change it to return an array [TimeModel]